# jquery: how to hide and show

Tags: jquery

I want to hide and show a `<p>` tag when mouse over it, but my code only can hide the `p` tag and never show it again ,why?

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#mouse").mouseover(function(){
      if($(this).is(':hidden')){
        $(this).show("normal");
      }
      else{
       $(this).hide("slow"); 
      }
    });
  });
</script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
   <p id="mouse">
     test
   </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use the toggle function instead of show and hide

Comment: When do you want to show it, and when do you want to hide it? It's very hard to mouseover something that isn't there. Impossible, in fact, I suspect. What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you will not have a mouseover event on a hidden p.

Comment: so  $("#mouse").mouseover(function() won't work after #mouse has hidden?

Comment: Mouseover event will not work if a div is hidden with display:none and unhidden with CSS-hover property. This is because display:none will generate no box for the div. workaround: use visibility: hidden. Probably this is why toggle behaves differently. Source. http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: so how I can do it? I am a new jquery programmer, so sorry can't understand visibility:hidden even after I use google

Comment: Try to study this function in order to modify different css properties one by one. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

When element is hidden you can't use any event with it. It would be better if you don't hide "p" but hide only element in "p".

**Example**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hidden").hover(function () {
     $(".hidden span").toggle();
  });
});
</script>

<p class='hidden'>please hover<span> Hide this text </span></p>
```